# What hashing strategy is recommended for desensitizing reporting data?

Tags: hash, anonymity

I need to desensitize data for reporting.  There may be some PII but nothing like SSN, mostly Name or Phone.  They won't be concatenated together anywhere.  Also this is in the US with no European (or other regions) data.

Given the same key and input the hash needs to create the same output. Therefore I can't use something like bcrypt, I don't believe.

I need to provide a key so that a single input is represented different across different reporting platforms, time periods, etc.  Example the name Fred Flintstone should be unique on a report for 2019, but different in 2020.

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517125/does-sha-2-hashing-use-a-key) I assume most hashing algorithms dont use keys.

Since hashing algorithms don't use keys would the best strategy be to pick Blowish or SHA512 and salt using the key?

Comment: why hashing and not encryption?

Comment: No reason for the data to be decrypted.  Basically just need unique hashes so we can do aggregate counts on things.

Comment: The salt would be your key. You could use a different salt for each version of the data subject you desired (different years, or other factors).

Comment: Anonymization is hard. People get bitten all the time for assuming "one way" hashes mean there is never a way to recover plaintext Two thumb rules: 1) Treat hashes of pieces of public information or short strings as equivalent to plaintext, 2) Treat plaintext as *potentially* recoverable from the hash unless there is some near-cryptographic-strength random SECRET incorporated in the input string. Safe: API keys, session IDs. Unsafe: Names, email/physical addresses, license plate numbers, URLs, dates, SSNs, CCNs, etc. Somewhere in between: Passwords. (No time for a real full answer.)

Comment: have you considered HMAC as a way of hashing with key ? you can use different key for each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since hashing algorithms don't use keys would the best strategy be to
>   pick Blowish or SHA512 and salt using the key?

With [HMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hmac-and-a-hash-of-data) you can use secret key to generate hash for sensitive data.

> I need to provide a key so that a single input is represented
>   different across different reporting platforms, time periods

Use different key for each different platform or time period.